# How to cascade kendo dropdownlist from kendo tree view

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

i am new to kendo treeview, presently i am trying to load the values of kendo dropdownlist based on kendo treeview checked checkbox values.i am abe to get the selected values of kendo treeview checked nodes, but not able to cascade the dropdownlist using those tree values.
can any one give some suggestion regarding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="treeview"></div>
    <div id="color"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true
                },

                check: onCheck,

                dataSource: [{
                    id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
                        {
                            id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                                { id: 3, text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                                { id: 4, text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                                { id: 5, text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            id: 6, text: "New Web Site", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                                { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg", spriteCssClass: "image" },
                                { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            id: 9, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                                { id: 10, text: "February.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                                { id: 11, text: "March.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                                { id: 12, text: "April.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            });
            $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value"
            });

        });
        function onCheck(arg) {
            var checkedNodes = [],
            treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),
            message;
            checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);

            //convert array to CSV
            var selectedIDs = checkedNodes.join(",");
            var ddl = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");

            // for testing purpose I have created dummy collection.
            var data = [
                       { text: "Red", value: "1" },
                       { text: selectedIDs, value: "2" },
                       { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
            ];
            ddl.setDataSource(data);

        }
        function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].checked) {
                    checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
                }
                if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                    checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
                }
            }
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,and its working perfect. i already achieved my desired functionality which is nearly same code as you provided.